# UITableView and UIView gesture conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add `UITableView` inside `UIView` but I got problem with gesture recognizer. This is my code:

```
    _subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenRect.size.height-100, screenRect.size.width, 300)];
    _subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.110f green:0.192f blue:0.298f alpha:1.00f];

    [self.view addSubview:_subView];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(subViewToggle)];
    [_subView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];



_moreTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, screenRect.size.width, 240)];        
        //Transforme to HOR scroll ;
         CGRect frame = _moreTable.frame;
        _moreTable.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, k90DegreesCounterClockwiseAngle);
        _moreTable.frame = frame;

        [_moreTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MoreTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"moreCell"];
        _moreTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
        _moreTable.delegate = self;
        _moreTable.dataSource = self;
        [_subView addSubview:_moreTable];
        [_subView bringSubviewToFront:_moreTable];
```

The problem is when I click on table cell instead of executing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method he execute the `subViewToggle` Method. I tried to bring my `tableView` to front but didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your tap gesture eat the touch. there are two way you can deal:

first, you can implement `- gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` delegate method, and decide if tap gesture should occur.

second, you also can set `cancelsTouchesInView` property of tap to NO, so tableView will receive touch. but tap will receive touch at the some time too.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol's `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

This should call both your didSelectRow and GestureRecognizer

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use like this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view == _moreTable]) {

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: do you mean `if (touch.view == _moreTable)` this didn't help I've added the delegate but it won't work because MyViewController is subClass of ScrollView and don't recognize the gesture.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this Problem I've changed the UIView Gesture from single finger tap to moveUP and moveDown gesture.
Note that I've tried only @dharmbir Solution and It haven't worked for me.
 
**Update** Also this solution, implementing the `shouldReciveTouches`, worked for the tapGesture and her's the code snippet :

```
 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
   // UITableViewCellContentView => UITableViewCell
   if([touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
       return NO;
   }
   // UITableViewCellContentView => UITableViewCellScrollView => UITableViewCell
   if([touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create tap gesture for menu transparent view
UITapGestureRecognizer *rightTableTransparentViewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightTableTransparentViewTapMethod:)];
[rightTableTransparentViewTap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[_rightTableTransparentView addGestureRecognizer:rightTableTransparentViewTap];

- (void)rightTableTransparentViewTapMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Write your code here
}
```